# Is this data normalization policy a good implementation?

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I am developing a database which will contain information from different applications where some multiselect tags contain multiple values in the same field.

For example the simplest case is that in one app exists the following selector:

```
You are: Lord
         Lady
```

Anther has this one:

```
You are: Monsieur
         Madame
```

Finally what I need in the centralized database (DataWarehouse) is a normalized table of what each customer is.

```
customer_id | customer_name | customer_type
--------------------------------------------
      1     |       John    |       Sir
      2     |        Sia    |     Madame
```

I think that to normalize this data while I develop the standardization of this data in the origin the best policy is to create auxiliary tables that save a relation of my normalized data (`output`) and the `input` data of the application.

For example:

My normalized expected values

```
   id  |  value 
----------------
    1  |   Sir  
    2  | Madame
```

My input expected values

```
   id  |  value 
----------------
    1  | Lord  
    2  | Lady 
    3  | Monsieur
    4  | Madame
```

My relational table

```
 id | normalized_value_id | expected_value_id
----------------------------------------------
 1  |           1         |          1
 2  |           1         |          3
 3  |           2         |          2
 4  |           2         |          4
```

I think that is the correct policy in this case because I do not know the exact values, and the exact relation with my expected input and my expected outputs once the values are normalized. 
Moreover I do not know the number of applications to normalize (maybe 2, maybe 100).

In this case If I have 2 apps to normalize at the beginning I can create my normalized expected values table without any complication, then I can add the input expected values while I discover new values, and then I relate this in the relational table without generate any affectation to the normalization process.

Furthermore, I can use these three tables to generate all the normalization process for all the multiselector for example:

Street multiselector:

```
You live: Str
          Ave
```

Another:

```
You live: St
         Av
```

My normalized expected values

```
   id  |  value 
----------------
    1  |   Sir  
    2  | Madame
    3  | Street
    4  | Avenue
```

My input expected values

```
   id  |  value 
----------------
    1  | Lord  
    2  | Lady 
    3  | Monsieur
    4  | Madame 
    5  | Str
    6  | St
    7  | Av
    8  | Ave
```

My relational table

```
 id | normalized_value_id | expected_value_id
----------------------------------------------
 1  |           1         |          1
 2  |           1         |          3
 3  |           2         |          2
 4  |           2         |          4
 5  |           3         |          5
 6  |           3         |          6
 7  |           4         |          7
 8  |           4         |          8
```

Is this implementation good enough and consistent for what I want to do?

Comment: @philipxy Why you say that? Finally what you do is to normalize data( with id's you can make reference to any of this values and then you are able to reduce data redundancy)

Comment: Database "normalization" reducing redundancy involves replacing a relation by others that join back to it. It doesn't involve adding ids. (If anything, that's data compression.) If you think it does, you need to read a textbook. When I first read your message, I edited your title, added tag "database-normalization" & commented that normalization doesn't involve adding ids. But then I thought you meant "normalizing" in the sense of systematically changing data values, as in statistics, per tag "normalization", as in convering many input values to one normalized one. So I undid those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - if you have not already checked out the ETL process, I would recommend it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

This plan looks good to me. I have two years of experience making custom analysis in a data warehouse. I would add a default mapping, so you can easily mark new values without using NULL and I would add a source-column on the table you use for mapping, but otherwise this seems like a good plan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have experience into ETL process. I will use these processes into the data transfering, and normalization process, but I want to have the normalization parameters into the database.

What do you mean with default mapping?  Do you mean for example assign a default value for any new value, like assign Sir to any new value in those multiselector type? I guess that you use the source-column to assign this default value, right?

Comment: Yes - the default mapping should be assigned to new values, that is not yet mapped, to avoid having to put NULL in the normalized values. Of course, the default should have a name, that would never be an expected or normalized value, so something like # or *. This is to avoid NULL's and I honestly don't know if it is a DWH best practice or just a preference. The source-column is only for convenience.

Comment: Further, I would start the normalized value id's around 1.000 to make room for default values below. One for each source.

Comment: I understand and I am agree with you. What I do not know is why to reserve about 1000 id's for default values, is not better to use only one dfault value or you just do this to differentiate between default values from each source?

Comment: Yes - 1.000 to be able to make default values for each source. You don't know how many sources that will be included, but I thought it would be less than 1.000 in the lifetime of the DWH. Having default values for each source, will hopefully make it less time consuming to identify from which source any new value originated.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is only need to apply for many-to-many relationship. I guess the relationship in these tables are 1-to-many. You should read how to implement solution for 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: It is true, but I do not know how many parameters will I have to normalize, so I do not see what is the improvement to avoid the relational table and use only a simple table to use 1-to-many relationship. Can anyone explain me that?

Comment: It doesn't matter on how many parameters you need to normalize. It first depends on the purpose of creating tables, for OLTP or OLAP. If you want to create tables for OLTP , you need to normalize your table until 4NF. If you want the tables work for OLAP, you need to denormalize tables.

Comment: As I am normalizing what I receive from apps (OLTP) to the DWH (OLAP) I think that i have to focus this as an OLAP nomalization process. What do you mean as denormalize table?

Comment: In your case I guess your database is OLTP, so try to normalize data and follow the normalization rule. Your question will be solved when you understand normalization rule and its purpose

Comment: Denormalization means you merge tables to one single table to fit with snowflake schema.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what do you mean. you talk about read about implement solution for 1-to-many relationship. Could you provide some example? I read about normalization, and I propose a plan to ensure that it is a correct implementation.

Comment: For one to many relationship you should make primary key of table in 1 to be the foreign key of table in many. For example, You can call John sir but there is no other chance that John is called by Mrs or Miss, so John only has one title to call. However, sir can be called by Martin, Peter etc. so primary key of title(sir) will appear in person table as foreign key. One title (sir) can be used by many people(John,Martin,Peter, etc), but one person can be called by only one title.

Comment: Right it is true, I must use the id of the expected value on the customer_type column on customer table. Furthermore this help to change the normalization value in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the plan seems ok. Perhaps the #1 thing for normalization: don't have columns mean more than one thing.

In practice, 1-to-Many is used most of the time. Essentially:

Table Title

```
ID  |  Desc
 1  |   Sir
 2  | Madam
```

Table Person

```
ID | Name | Title
 1 | Dean |   1
 2 | Jess |   2
```

Where only titles are added to the Title table. Only Persons are in the person table but the Title ID can be anything in Title. When doing Many-Many, you want to keep this same concept.